# Nginx не отображает статику в django 1.9

Tags: linux, nginx

Настраиваю `nginx` по этой [ссылке](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn).
Но `django` не видит статику ни в админке, ни в проекте.

```
#settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'djangoenv/static'
```

`ls -al /root`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#nginx
server { server_name detsky-sadik.ru;
 access_log off; 
location /static/ { 
alias /djangoenv/static/; } 
location / {
 proxy_pass http://detsky-sadik.ru:8001; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name; 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"'; } }
```

Статику на сервере собирал. Погуглив, попробовал добавить `mime.types` в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/det_sad`, но `nginx` ругался на это.
Просьба помочь.

Comment: покажите конфиг nginx'a, без него вряд ли можно что-то конкретное сказать

Comment: Перенесите конфиг из комментария в вопрос. А так сразу видно что: вы статику в nginx'е отдаете по **абсолютному** пути `/djangoenv/static/`, но ведь у вас скорее всего `djangoenv` не в корне ФС лежит? Ведь STATIC_ROOT = 'djangoenv/static' у вас это **относительный** путь, значит, если вы делали по туториалу, то скорее всего у вас должно быть в конфиге nginx'а `/opt/djangoenv/static/`

Comment: Я делал без `opt`. У меня после `root` идёт сразу `djangoenv/static`. То есть по идее путь верный.

Comment: Очень плохая идея засорять корень. А так сделайте `ls -al /` и дайте вывод (все выкладывайте в вопрос, не в комментарии), возможно, у nginx'а просто нет прав на чтение этой папки

Comment: И заодно посмотрите, ваш `djangoenv` РЕАЛЬНО есть в корне? ведь `STATIC_ROOT = 'djangoenv/static'` намекает на то, что папка, создаваемая `collectstatic`, будет лежать где-то относительно папки с проектом, а не в корне

Comment: Первый раз разворачиваю на сервере. Так что не знаю где лучше хранить. Папку со статикой хранил как в корне приложения, так и в корне с `virtualenv` и всё было без изменений.

Comment: ну теперь то видите, что в корне нет папки со статикой? короче, ищите, где эта папка РЕАЛЬНО лежит. вангую, что она лежит в папке с проектом рядом с manage.py

Comment: Папка находится по этому пути `root/djangoenv/static`. Я вставил этот путь в конфиг. Статику так же не грузит.

Comment: Ну вот, а в конфиге nginx'а вы пишете `/djangoenv/static`, когда у вас статика в `/root/djangoenv/static/`. Только вставляйте в конфиг АБСОЛЮТНЫЙ (то есть с начальным слешом) путь, а то черт его знает, что nginx считает рабочей папкой, но точно не корень ФС.

Comment: Абсолютный это такого плана? `//root/djangoenv/static/`. Если да, то не работает

Comment: С один слешом вначале. И проверьте права доступа к `djangoenv` (`ls -al /root`), так как `root` это папка суперпользователя, и к ней никто кроме него обычно не имеет доступ.

Comment: Попробуйте сменить права доступа к папке djangoenv: `chmod 777 -R /root/djangoenv`

Comment: Не работает.Нашёл у себя в корне `djangoenv/static`. Изменил в settings.py `STATIC_ROOT` на `/root/djangoenv/static` и пересобрал статику.Никого результата. Что это вообще может быть?

Comment: Хорошей идеей было бы посмотреть логи nginx'a (`/var/log/nginx/access.log` и `error.log`). Также ради интереса можно переместить статику в `/tmp`, выставить ей владельца `nginx` и права 777, и посмотреть, будет ли так работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблемы тем, что удалил дроплет и поставил новый с другим туториалом. Спасибо `Flowneee` за попытки помочь:)